# How do I sell points using a new product type?

Tags: commerce, rules

With the Drupal commerce module, I created a new product type I use for selling points to my customers. The product has a custom field named “points” (field type integer) where I specify the amount of point to sell.

On checkout I want to grant the points to the user (with the Userpoint module). I want to do this with rules.

The problem is that I can’t retrieve the field “points” in action rules. I tried adding the “entity has field” condition, but I am not able to retrieve the field from the commerce order.

The action is *grants points to a user*.

> [image: Config screenshot]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Define "non able to retrieve the field". Show us the code you wrote for your custom action, or screenshot from config screen if it's a built-in action.

Comment: Molot is right, Please give us as much information as possible in order to help you and answer your question.

Comment: Action: grant points to a user. User (The user that will receive the points) commerce-order:owner. But I cant retrieve Points (Amount of points to give or take) that i want to be the value of "points" field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question in order to give you a solution. That people can "top" up here is maybe an alternative.

[Drupal Userpoint Feature request](https://drupal.org/node/1270290)

> Remember to use dev version.

[Commerce Userpoints](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_userpoints)

What about something like this ?

- 1) Rule

Event: on payment completed
Action: loop through the order line-items. Each line-item has an action to call the next component with parameters of order and the line-item.

- 2) Component

Parameters: order, line-item
Condition: data comparison line-item:type is Product (to expose line-item:commerce-product)
Action: call next component with parameters of order and line-item:commerce-product

- 3) Component

Parameters: order, product
Condition: data comparison product:type is Product (to expose the product:field-points-to-add)

- Action: add userpoints, number to add being
  product:field-points-to-add

Comment: This module allows to buy discount with points, not to buy points for money. Or am I missing something? Please elaborate.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I expose line-item:commerce-product and product:field-points-to-add with entity is of  type end entity has field. The rule works! but only if the quantity is one; if I buy more quantity the points granted is always the same.